# PowerShell Script to list computers/servers in a subnet mask

Tags: powershell

I am currently using a powershell script to return last active computers and the respective domain hosts on AD as shown below:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -properties *|select Name, DNSHostName, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate
```

What I want to do next is to list all the computers/servers within the subnet of 255.255.251.0 that use the username "Administrator." How would I go about achieving this through editing my above script?

Comment: IP address/subnet are not stored in AD; however AD computer objects have a `dnsHostName` attribute. You would have to retrieve all computer accounts, get the `dnsHostName` attribute, look that up, and then retrieve the network mask (perhaps using WMI). This requires the computer to be up and assumes you have access to it to retrieve this information.

Comment: So there is no way to output computer names on a particular subnet? @Bill_Stewart

Comment: If you start with a network ID (which is what I assume you mean by "subnet"), you can use some [IPv4 code I wrote in an article for Windows IT Pro](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell-scripting/working-ipv4-addresses-powershell) and use the output to try to connect to computers and get members of groups.

Comment: Do you have to use powershell for that? nmap would be a better way in my opinion.

Comment: @RohinSidharth I am not familiar with nmap but have an idea on how it is done. It can achieve the results I want?

Comment: Yes, it uses mechanisms similar to other network discovery or inventory management tools. You could make your own inventory management tool out of it if you tried.